# Nuclear weapons and stability

Tags: nuclear-weapons

What are the arguments that nuclear weapons can provide some form of global stability in a multipolar and/or bipolar world?

Comment: Welcome to Politics SE!  This would be an excellent question for a debating society, but it is not a good fit for our Q&A format as any answers would be opinion-based.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about what is on-topic here, and if you can [edit] this question in a way that makes it on-topic, then please do so.

Comment: It can be argued. It can also be argued that nuclear weapons provide instability, especially in a multipolar setting. (Many MAD models assume exactly two actors and it seems to have worked over several decades.) But that debate isn't what Stackexchange is about. The site developed from *technical* Q&A and it should be possible to tell right answers from wrong ones.